# Suppress error: Can't chmod() in Archive::Zip

Tags: perl, zip, archive

I am trying to extract some files using Archive::Zip.
Everything is working fine. The files are being extracted with no issues. Here is the parth of the code:

```
my $zip = Archive::Zip->new($file);
foreach my $member ($zip->members) {
    next if $member->isDirectory;
    (my $extractName = $member->fileName) =~ s{.*/}{};
    $member->extractToFileNamed($unixPath{'Rdrive'}.$extractName);
}
```

I am getting the following warning when running the script:

> error: Can't chmod() /test/test.txt: Operation not permitted

I was trying to find a way to suppress this message in Archive::Zip, but was not able to find any way to do it. I am not able to change the permissions of the server. What would be the best way to suppress this message?

Thank you,
-Andrey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*$member->unixFileAttributes(0644);* does not seem to work because the files are being extracted on the network drive.
I solved the problem by using:

```
Archive::Zip::setErrorHandler( \&zipErrorHandler );
```

Answer (score 0):

the archive, which your script try to extract, is created with some issues on permissions at file `test.txt`. for some reasons this permissions cannot be chmod-ed in your system, so you got this error.

you can fix this permissions by adding `$member->unixFileAttributes(0644);` before extracting line `$member->extractToFileNamed()`. also you can try to investigate the real reason by printing this permissions: `printf "%o - %s\n", $member->unixFileAttributes(0644), $member->fileName();`

Comment: Thanks for reply. I tried the solution and it does not work. print statement prints 666. It does not change it to 644.

Comment: The print is showing the old permissions value since **unixFileAttributes** returns the old value when use to set a value.

Comment: is the warning "error: Can't chmod() /test/test.txt: Operation not permitted" printed for all files in archive or only for one? show here contents of ``ls -la /test`` command. make small archive, which repeats this error and do it available to download from somewhere. which version of Archive::Zip are you using?